# Create Data Mapping in Salesforce

Tags: reporting, data-model

I have a scenario  where I have opportunity object. There are few fields in this object let say

1. Country (Picklist)
2. State (Picklist)
3. City (Picklist)

Now I want a report where I want region as a field in opportunity, but this field has multiple permutation/combination which client has provided us in an excel sheet. Lets say for Country US and state Washington DC and City Washington region would be Area 1, in this way there are many regions.

Problem is I need to create this new region field and populate the data in this field based on the excel sheet they have shared.  What approach I should go with ?

I thought for creating a separate object as region and creating a field 'region' also in opportunity object. And than add records manually in this new region object based on the excel provided. and than whenever new opportunity record is created I can fetch mappings like for this country, state, city what's the corresponding value we have in region field in Region object and populate that in opportunity region field. But here problem is there is ample amount of data in excel sheet which cant be added manually neither by any loader.

Shall we use custom metadata here? if so how we can use custom metadata here?

Is there any other solution which I am missing ?

I would be thankful for any help

Comment: SFDC territory management?

Comment: +1 for enterprise territory mgmt.  Also, why work at the opportunity level when all the data points are alrady at the account level (including Area if you have to make it a custom field)?

Comment: No, cant use SFDC territory management here.  Need a solution which can be used for other objects also for similar kind of mapping scenarios

Comment: Then you'll have to use custom metadata.  You can concatenate the city/state/country values into a single index value and map that to a region value.